# Linux can't boot without acpi=off on Thinkpad

Tags: linux, grub, thinkpad, acpi, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint 12 - the Gnome version - on a new Lenovo Thinkpad `L520` for a friend.

It's running `kernel 3.0.0-12- generic`.

When I booted - either into the live CD, or into the installed system - it would get stuck on this message:

```
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
```

I eventually figured out I could get it to work with this boot flag:

```
acpi=off
```

So I booted into the live CD with that flag, installed it, mounted the new system from the live CD and chrooted into it, added the `acpi=off` flag and ran `update-grub`.

It all boots fine now, but obviously there's no ACPI. It doesn't report battery status, and the one time my friend unplugged it it seemed to turn off immediately.

Is there some way around this? Can I somehow determine whether this laptop would work in a more recent kernel? Or can I somehow insert ACPI support in at a later time, after boot?

Comment: I had similar issues on a different machine. What helped me was to add `processor.nocst=1` instead of turning the whole acpi off.

Comment: Unfortunately that had no effect. Since I had this problem across distros maybe I need to find some kernel folk to ask..